# Can I know data type from variable name in GCC?

Tags: gcc

I want to know data type using variable name

My final goal is getting a function signature for making a function stub(skeleton code)

but GCC error message just notify only undefined function name

Can I see a symbol table? (for inferencing function signature)

for example, foo.c is like below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    n = foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to make a function stub

so I want to know function foo has no parameter and returns an integer value

What should I do?

I think below:

1. linker error message say function foo is undefined
2. read line 5

   n = foo();
3. inspect type of n using symbol table

is it right?

sorry for my bad english

please teach me inferencing a function signature

Comment: but function signature is not related to linker errors

Comment: perreal thank you i know that. so i want to see a symbol table.... what should i do?

Comment: A C symbol table does not have any type information. Internally, the compiler obviously has to build and use type information, but that doesn't go into the object files.

Comment: Sounds like he wants the debugging symbol table, like gdb uses.

Comment: Is `foo` defined in a header file, and you just don't know where? Or is it not defined anywhere, and you're depending on being able to link without prototypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject his code into your source file:

```
typedef struct { int a; char c; } badtype_t;
badtype_t badtype;
```

then replace the error line like this:

```
n = badtype; //foo();
```

or if you want the type `foo` returns:

```
badtype = foo();
```

then you will get some error like this:

```
incompatible types when initializing type ‘int’ using type ‘badtype_t’
```

and you can get the type `int`.

or if you want the type of `foo` itself:

```
foo * 2
```

then you will get some error like this:

```
invalid operands to binary * (have 'int (*)()' and 'int')
```

and you can get the type `int (*)()` (that is, function taking nothing and returning an int).

Comment: I think he's trying to get the type of `foo` and/or `foo()`, not the type of `n` (which he already has in the line directly above).

Comment: @abarnert, it's easy to tweak this to get the type of foo. updated.

Comment: With `clang`, I get a useful answer: `error: initializing 'badtype_t' with an expression of incompatible type 'int'`. But with gcc, whether 4.2 or 4.8, I just get this: `error: invalid initializer`.

Comment: gcc 4.8.1 `incompatible types when assigning to type ‘badtype_t’ from type ‘long int’`. They may be a way to make gcc spell out the type in earlier versions.

Comment: Aha. In 4.8.0, you get a useful error in _reassignment_, but not _initialization_; in 4.2.1, you don't get a useful error either way. (I don't have any in-between versions lying around to test.)

Comment: By the way, can you figure out any way to get gcc (any version) to give you the type of `foo` itself rather than `foo()`? With `clang`, doing `badtype = foo` tells me `incompatible pointer types assigning to 'badtype_t *' from 'double (double)'`, but gcc just says `assignment from incompatible pointer type`.

Comment: Meanwhile, rereading the question… he's getting a _linker error_ about `foo` not being defined, so I think all of this is a massive red herring. He's just trying to call a function that doesn't exist…

Comment: @abarnert, if you do `foo * 2`, it says `error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘double (*)(double)’ and ‘int’)`

Comment: Aha! That works for gcc-4.2, and even 4.0, as well as clang and gcc-4.8. Nice trick. I edited it into your answer, because it seems like the ideal way to do… what the OP may or may not want, but what most people searching this question will probably want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok, but this strategy will not be good enough.  Using the left-hand side of an expression is not enough to determine the return-type of the function.  In particular, there may be no left-hand side at all, simply: `foo();`.  What then?

Comment: Our goal is just making no compile error. So we don't want exact return type. How do I inference a return type?

Comment: You could stub out a function that returns void, then see what kind of future errors you get.  You might get something along the lines of _.. this function returns "void" and cannot be converted to "int"_

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see a symbol table, that's what [`nm`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?nm) is for.

For example, if you get an error linking `foo.o` and `bar.o` together, you can do this:

```
nm -a foo.o
```

That will show you all the symbols defined in module `foo`.

But I don't see why you think this would help. C symbols do not have any type information. There may be enough metadata to distinguish extern linkage, and/or to tell whether a symbol function or data, but that's it. There is no way to tell an `int` from a `float`, or a function taking two `int`s and returning a `double` from a function taking a `char *` and returning a different `char *`.

Comment: um... ok thank you for your answer! and then how do i inference a function signature?

Comment: Technically, you can't. Practically, you do it by asking the compiler for help.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have some function named `foo` defined *somewhere*, and you want to know what its type is.

If you don't actually have a prototype for `foo` somewhere in your `#include`d header files, this is easy:

- If you're using C99, your code is invalid.
- Otherwise, `foo` must take no arguments and return `int`, or your code is invalid.

And this isn't one of those "technically invalid, but it works on every platform" cases; it *will* break. For example, with gcc 4.2 for 64-bit x86 linux or Mac, if you do this:

```
double foo(double f) { return f*2; }
```

Then, without a header file, call it like this:

```
double f = foo(2.0);
printf("%f\n", f);
```

If compiled as C89, this will compile and link just fine (clang or gcc 4.8 will give you a warning; gcc 4.2 won't even do that by default), and run, and print out `2.0`. At least on x86_64; on ARM7, you'll corrupt the stack, and segfault if you're lucky. (Of course it actually does double something—either your 2.0 or some random uninitialized value—but it can't return that to you; it's stashed it in an arbitrary floating-point register that the caller doesn't know to access.)

---

If it *is* in a header file, you can always search for it. emacs, graphical IDEs, etc. are very good at this. But you can use the compiler to help you out, in two ways.

First, just do this:

```
gcc -E main.c > main.i
less main.i
```

Now search for `/foo`, and you'll find it.

Or you can trick the compiler into giving you an error message, as in perreal's answer.